# Borrar archivos de una carpeta sin saber el nombre de usuario atravez de codigo batch

Tags: batch

trabajo en una oficina y casi todos los días me mandan hacerle limpieza a las computadoras, son como 20 y tiene instalado un software que desinstala cada 24 horas todo software instalado, solo necesito borrar los archivos que se van guardando en la carpeta `C:\Users\Nombre de Usuario\AppData\Roaming`.

Puesto a que todas la computadoras tienen nombres de usuarios diferentes, entonces dije puedo crear un batch, nada más de ejecutarlo y limpia esa carpeta pero la ruta es el problema, existe alguna manera de escbriir una ruta que el nombre de usuario no sea un pronlema?

```
Echo off
del /s /f /q C:\Users\Nombre de Usuario\AppData\Roaming
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas `%appdata%`, vas a poder apuntar a la carpeta Roaming de un usuario.

Ej:

```
C:\Users\user> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>cd %appdata%

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming>
```

Ya desde ahí puedes navegar el árbol de subdirectorios que conoces.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero me puedas dar una ejemplo de como lo aplico al comando?                      echo off
cd C:\Users\Ejemplo\AppData\Roaming
del /f /q /S *.*
exit

Comment: @BodyBoard podrías añadir tu código EN la pregunta? Es difícil leerlo correctamente en un comentario. :)

Comment: Listo y gracias por tomar interés en el mi pregunta amigo.